# GitHub Actions Artifact Retrieval

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub Repository with a GitHub Action designed to run daily.
The Action itself generates a CSV file which I upload as an artifact:

```
- name: Upload CSV artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: results-csv
          path: output/*.csv
          if-no-files-found: warn
          retention-days: 7
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that if for example the Job Ran on Monday and stored the CSV artifact, and then it runs on Monday i want to pull the retained Artifact. and compare the changes in the data between the two executions.
I already know how to pull it :

```
# Download Artifacts
      - name: Download all workflow run artifacts
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
```

The way I want it the Action to run is something like this:

1. Pull the retained artifact
2. Run the code which will generate a new artifact, compare the difference between the 2 of them.
3. Upload the new artifact.
   The Problem is that when i run the Action in this order i get this :

> No artifact name specified, downloading all artifacts
> Creating an extra directory for each artifact that is being downloaded
> Unable to find any artifacts for the associated workflow
> There were 0 artifacts downloaded
> Artifact download has finished successfully

What am I missing in the configuration ? or is it what i'm trying to achieve is not doable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to do this using a custom GitHub Action :

```
dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2
```

The key is to specify the following:

```
workflow : <<The name of the workflow file (.yml)>>
workflow_conclusion: success
commit: ${{github.event.pull_request.head.sha}}
```